# Как добавить cookies в запрос с HttpClient Angular 5

Tags: cookie, angular5

В клиент серверное приложение пытаюсь добавить аутентификацию (Back-end на Java на другом сервере вся передача данных через REST), столкнулся с проблемой - при отправке следующего запроса, после удачной аунтефикации, `Angular 5` не прикрепляет `cookies` к запросу. Тоесть сама аунтефикация проходит нормально, логин и пароль принимаются, происходит переадресация на защищенную часть приложения, но следующий запрос уже обрабатывается сервером как `Unauthorized`. 
В вкладке `Network` следующая картина:

При запросе на аутентификацию:

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/user/login?username=1@1&password=12345
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 230
Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 14:31:08 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C19E560EBF7C0F96FCE7361ECE1B7D12; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Тоесть `Cookie` приходят.

А при следующем запросе для заполнения таблицы с данными:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/vds/list?pageNumber=0&pageSize=15
```

В запросе выданных сервером `Cookie` нигде нет:

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/vds/list?pageNumber=0&pageSize=15
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Responce 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 14:31:27 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/vds-list
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
```

Так у меня реализованы запросы к серверу:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoreApi {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public get(url: string = ''): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.getUrl(url));
  }

  public post(url: string, data: any = {}): Observable < any > {
    return this.http.post(this.getUrl(url), data);
  }

  private getUrl(url: string = ''): string {
    return this.baseUrl + url;
  }
}
```

И все сервисы уже от него наследутся что-то в таком духе:

```
@Injectable()
export class VdsService extends CoreApi {

    constructor(public http : HttpClient) {
        super(http);
    }

    getVdsList() : Observable < Vds[] > {
        return this.get(`vds/list?pageNumber=0&pageSize=15`).map((data : Vds[]) => data);
    }

}
```

Я предполагаю что наверное процесс управления `Сookie` должен быть на уровне `CoreApi`, но как это сделать. В процессе гугления запутался еще больше, где-то написанно что `Angular` должен делать это сам, а где-то что это делается с помощью `Http Interceptor`...

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как мне в данном контексте корректно добвлять полученные при аунтефикации `Cookie`, во все последующие запросы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установленные сервером куки автоматически передаются в последующих запросах (если конечно совпадет хост, путь и прочие параметры). Никаких специальных действий не требуется. Возможно причина в чем-то другом. К тому же судя по параметру `HttpOnly` у куки вы все равно не сможете получить к ней доступ из JS. Если же требуется как-то вмешиваться в HTTP запросы так сказать *en masse* то смотрите в сторону [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)